# Current Culture in New Threads At .Net is same for all thread which is not that I expected

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, ubuntu, cultureinfo

As I read in the Microsoft documentation, new Thread should use the default system Locale as culture but It is not the case in my code. Is this a bug that I should report to .Net team or this is the correct behaviour? This is my example and the result It returns:

```
static Random rng = new Random();
static void DisplayThreadInfo()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Thread Name:{Thread.CurrentThread.Name}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Current Culture:{Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Current UI Culture:{Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Default Thread Culture is {CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture}"); // If this is null, current system culture used as default culture for new threads, 
}
static void DisplaySomeCultureDependentValues()
{
    // Show three random number as currency
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}th Value:{1:C2}", i, rng.NextDouble() * 10000);
    }
}
static void ThreadProc()
{
    DisplayThreadInfo();
    DisplaySomeCultureDependentValues();
}
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name != "ja-JP")
    {
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ja-JP");
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ja-JP");
    }
    else
    {
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
    }
    ThreadProc();
    // Create a new thread and run ThreadProc with it
    Thread thread = new Thread(ThreadProc);
    thread.Name = "Worker Thread";
    thread.Start();

    // Use Thread Pool instead of creation of thread
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((obj) => ThreadProc());
}
```

An this is the result:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your response

Comment: You are setting `CurrentCulture` to `ja-JP`. What is strange now?! And what is your .net version?

Comment: this is what Microsoft says:"When a new application thread is started, its current culture and current UI culture are defined by the current system culture, and not by the current thread culture." so It should use my locale not my selected culture in new thread. I am using .Net 6. See following link please:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-7.0#culture-and-threads

Comment: You're running on Linux right? So that's legacy Mono. I noticed the culture for Mono Webassembly is not always as expected either. It wouldn't surprise me if this is a Mono thing. Couldn't hurt to raise an issue in dotnet/runtime or certainly search there for similar issues.

Comment: @PeterMoore Yes it is Linux Ubuntu. As in documents they recommend it, I think it is better to specify culture wherever I need it specifically.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation lacks the details but this behaviour is correct. The old behaviour was [changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.5.2-4.6#currentculture-and-currentuiculture-flow-across-tasks) since .Net Framework 4.6. It is caused by the current culture being set to a different culture from the system culture and the transfer of the [execution context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.executioncontext?view=net-7.0). When the new thread starts, its execution context will be restored by the execution context of the invoker. If you want to avoid such behaviour, use [Thread.UnsafeStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.unsafestart?view=net-7.0).

Comment: I think this is the case in Asynchronous Task-Based Operations. I do not have windows OS to check and see what is the result in windows. If both are same, then it is the case in all thread even data-based asynchronous operation too which make more sense. Thanks for your response